# Write comma separated unicode in android textview

Tags: android, unicode, hex

Hello friends i have one hexadecimal code

```
String ss=54,44,24
```

i want to wrote in android like below

```
text.setText("\u54\u44\u24");
```

but show me error like **"Invalid Unicode"**  any idea how can i write it?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to setText Unicode than you can use [This font](https://groups.google.com/group/tamil_ulagam/attach/47953ebb6d9f23d4/TAU_BHON.TTF?part=0.8&authuser=0)

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "TAU_BHON.TTF");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

and second way is use `Html.fromHtml()`

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("\\u27A1");
```

Comment: Milap : can you give me TAU_BHON.TTF file download link ?

Comment: i tried you code but i m not getting RD$ currency symbol when i convert hex code with this ttf file

Comment: No second also not work it display like \u2741 not RD$ symbol

Comment: what you want to print ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66977/discussion-between-harshal-kalavadiya-and-milaptank).

Comment: I want to display RD$ currency symbol with the help of unicode charater

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
mport org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
...

String hexString = Hex.encodeHexString(myString.getBytes(/* charset */));
```

Comment: Milad : how can i write charset ?